# Error with Schema - ReferenceError: Phone is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I'm having a small problem when building a CRUD Api with node.js and express.

When I post to my API I get "ReferenceError: Phone is not defined"

```
// server.js
```

// BASE SETUP
// =============================================================================

// call the packages we need

```
var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var phone = require('./models/phone');


var mongoose = require('mongoose');




 mongoose.connect('mongodb://<userID>:<pass>@apollo.modulusmongo.net:27017/ugygY5qe');



// configure app to use bodyParser()
// this will let us get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;        // set our port

// ROUTES FOR OUR API
// =============================================================================
var router = express.Router();              // get an instance of the express Router
router.use(function(req,res,next){
  console.log('Something is happening');
  next();
});


router.route('/phones').post(function(req, res){
  var phone = new Phone();
  phone.name = req.body.name;

  phone.save(function(err){
    if(err){
      res.send(err);
    }
    res.json({message: 'Phone Create'});
  });
});
// test route to make sure everything is working (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api)
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });
});

// more routes for our API will happen here

// REGISTER OUR ROUTES -------------------------------
// all of our routes will be prefixed with /api
app.use('/api', router);

// START THE SERVER
// =============================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

And here is my schema file.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var phoneSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Phone', phoneSchema);
```

I'm not sure where the error is. I've consulted the mongoose docs, search around but still can't get anything to work.

Comment: You meant `var Phone = require('./models/phone');`, but you specified the variable in lower case instead.

Comment: You are a life saver! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a typo ! check line no 4.

```
var Phone = require('./models/phone');
```